# What is Laravel using PHPParser(nikic) for?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, php-parser

I'm [facing an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32927948/laravel-4-using-nikic-phpparser-going-out-of-memory-when-sending-email) where the parser is going out of memory -

- /nikic/php-parser/lib/PHPParser/Node/Expr/Identical.php on line 25
- /nikic/php-parser/lib/PHPParser/Parser.php  on line 1044

And this is happening when I'm sending an **email** at that too in only a scenario.
I'm trying to understand what Laravel is trying to do here, so I can resolve this issue.

Laravel version 4.0
PHPHarser verison 0.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your memory limit is set a 32 megabytes. This is extremely low. The amount of information that is being processed in your script is simply greater than that amount.

The correct solution is to increase your memory limit.